# Broadband modem fails to get connected in Ubuntu 12.10.

Tags: 12.10, modem, broadband

I am now unable to connect to internet with a huwaei E173s-1.

The modem worked perfectly in 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04 now it gets detected, but cannot be connected at all.

Any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Yes I've had the same problem with two other devices after update 12.10 (worked fine with 12.04). 
My Solution downgrade modem-manager (to deb of 12.04)

download deb:
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/98148171/modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb 
from (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/modemmanager/0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2)

and the install the old version:

```
sudo dpkg -i modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

to prevent update to version 0.6.x lock the version in synaptic.
After downgrade I got the question for PIN immediately.

NOTE: Give ubuntu a change to repair, so keep in touch of update of 0.6.x version ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have manual steps to configure it.

1. First of all open up the terminal and run the following command

   `sudo apt-get update`
2. Now we need to install wvdial so run the following command

   `sudo apt-get install wvdial`
3. Now we need to install libusb-dev so run the following command

   `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev`
4. Now we need to download usb-modeswitch and usb-modeswitch-data so go to the following links
   usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data . Download both the files and save them on your computer .
5. Now extract both the files and and go to extracted directories on by one (first go to usb-modeswitch). and run the following command as root

   `sudo make install`
6. Now run the following command

   `sudo gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf`

and it will open gedit and paste the following text in it and save the file

```
# Configuration for the usb-modeswitch package, a mode switching tool for
# USB devices providing multiple states or modes
# This file is evaluated by the wrapper script "usb_modeswitch" in /lib/udev
      # To enable an option, set it to "1", "yes" or "true" (case doesn't matter)
# Everything else counts as "disable"
# Disable automatic mode switching globally (e.g. to access the original
      # install storage)
DisableSwitching=0
# Enable logging (results in a extensive report file in /var/log, named
# "usb_modeswitch_"
EnableLogging=1
# Huawei, newer modems
DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
      DefaultProduct=0x1446
TargetVendor= 0x12d1
TargetProduct=140b
CheckSuccess=5
```

7.  Now run the following commands

```
`sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf`
```

it will again open gedit and you need to paste the following text in it.

```
[Dialer netconnect]
New PPPD = yes
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = USB Modem
Baud = 460800
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
ISDN = 0
Username = 93********
      Password = 93*********
Phone = #777
Stupid Mode = 1
Auto DNS = 1
Check Def Route = 1
```

change the username and password with your 10 digit MDN number given on the box of datacard.
8. Now Save the file and reboot the computer. After reboot plugin your datacard and wait for 5 to 6 seconds . Now run the following command

```
sudo wvdial netconnect
```

you should see something like below after running the above command

```
--> Using interface ppp0
--> local  IP address 115.242.127.250
--> remote IP address 220.224.141.129
--> primary   DNS address 202.138.97.193
```

Comment: The following links in step 4 never did follow...

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in ModemManager 0.6.0.0 which comes with Ubuntu 12.10.

You should use ModemManager 5.2.0.0

Install the following packages:

- [modemmanager-dbg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/modemmanager-dbg)
- [modemmanager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/modemmanager)

After reboot works the Modem fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/network/interfaces by

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces in terminal

Conform that file should have following parameters.

> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet dhcp

Save file reboot system.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative easier solution is to start your modem in windows OS, and configure it to use a hybrid mode. Usually, your vendor includes drivers that work out-of-the-box but only on Windows. For example, Tata-Photon includes a GUI tool that enables you to switch between Photon-Plus, Plug-to-surf and Hybrid-mode. The third option will enable your broadband to work out of the box even on linux without installing wvdial or doing other advanced configurations.